# OnCollisionEnter2D isn't working and I don't know why

Tags: 2d

I'm new to Unity and c# and I'm trying to get the basics down but I seem to be having some trouble with the collision. I want to get a falling object to destroy when it collides with another object that is stationary. All of the objects are set to Box Collider 2D in Unity and after hours of searching I can't seem to figure out what's wrong with it. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
using UnityEngine;
```

using System.Collections;

public class Destroy : MonoBehaviour {

```
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    transform.position = new Vector2 (0, -10);
    Debug.Log ("Game Start");
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "Target") //|| (col.gameObject.tag == "fallingCube2")) 
    {
        Debug.Log ("There has been a collision!");
        Destroy (col.gameObject);
    }
    else 
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "otherTarget")
    {
        Debug.Log ("There has been a collision!");
        Destroy (col.gameObject);
    }
```

}
}

Comment: You should include the relevant parts of code in the post - or all of it, seeing as this is such a short piece of code. Not everyone willing to answer is willing to follow links, and the link might fail to work at any time due to several possible reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the Tag is the same (care with uppercase), and use col.tag == "Target".

The GameObject must have and BoxCollider2D or other Collider2D with the property isTrigger to false.

I always use OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col) because I dont want that my pj stops falling or whatever